# Loop SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I will be provided with student **number** and class ID in an excel sheet and would like to write a bulk insert query that does the following for each student

1. Insert a record for each student along with their class ID in the StudentClass Table (only if the combination of student Id + Class ID does not exists)
2. Create a static note for each of those created students in the Notes Table the note can be something like "New class added".

Here is a sample of the database [Sample Database for Students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgOnY.jpg)

I am new to SQL and hoping someone can help me with this complicated query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's too much to ask for....

Comment: There are definitely a bunch of helpful people here at SO. But you'll get much more out of this assignment if you put in the effort first.  If you get stuck, post the SQL you have written and a description of why it's not working.

Comment: This is too much "do my homework for me" to get much of an answer.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the great input .I just mentioned that I am new to SQL. I know how to do a simple insert . import and export data through SQL import wizard. bulk insert based with Select Statement but I never wrote a loop or anything of that complex. So pardon me that I am not smart enough as you guys to figure this on my own. Great feedback. Yes I do not know how to do this. Yes. I have never written anything this complex before since I just started programming. So Pardon me that I asked someone to simply write a query for me that I might learn from and use and alter for future tasks.

Comment: This is too broad for SO. I would start, though, by bulk inserting everything in excel into a new table, then [merge those records](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) into your first table, and insert into the second table. It won't be one complex sql statement. It will be a couple of rather simple ones.

Comment: Think you are missing the point. Your question does not show any effort at all. It comes across as "here is my assignment, please do it for me". We want to help you learn. The whole teach a man to fish mentality. If we write this for you all we have done is given you a fish. When you demonstrate that you are trying to figure it out people here are more than willing to help. But when you say "here do this for me", not many are willing to do that.

Comment: @MazBaz have you written any part of the query?  That at least gives us a place to start.  You can mockup the portions you are having difficulties with with comments ie `--I will insert static text here`.  You will encounter more specific issues, along the way.  Some references [Here](http://sqlhints.com/2015/06/21/looping-through-table-records-in-sql-server/) and [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php)